# How many polygons or vertices are said to be a low poly?

Tags: vertices, polycount

I started designing a model in blender. The finished model has 60K vertices and 108K tris. I want it to be atleast a medium-poly model. I have used decimate modifier to bring down the poly count. Is this poly count good enough for a low poly model or should I reduce the polygons further?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Whether model's polycount is low/high depends entirely on your needs, intended usage and other variables. Please [rephrase the question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so it can be answered more objectively, otherwise it will probably get closed as [off-topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Meanwhile, Wikipedia seems to have an [entire page about Low Poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_poly). Isn't that nice?